# Uniform convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

Test the uniform convergence of the series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^2 - n^2 \pi^2}$$

$$ \forall z \not= \pm  n\pi,\;\; where n \in\mathbb N$$

Can I find $M_n$ such that $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^2 - n^2 \pi^2}\lt \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}M_n<+\infty\;\;\;\;\;\;\;?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if $|z2−n2π2|≥n2π2$, then your initial inequality holds.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a sequence $M_{n}$ such that 
$$|\frac{1}{z^{2} - n^{2}\pi^{2}}| \le M_{n}$$
and se you can take $M_{n} = \frac{1}{n^{2}\pi^{2}}.$

EDIT: Wait, what I wrote is just nonsense. The bound goes the other way in my example. Please ignore it.

Comment: What if $z$ is extremely close to $n\pi$?

Comment: @GregMartin I wrote some nonsense sorry. I got the bound the other way.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh Actually, if $|z^2-n^2\pi^2| \ge n^2\pi^2$, then your initial inequality holds. Check my comment above yours.

Comment: Is it always true  $|z^2-n^2\pi^2|\gt n^2\pi^2$

Comment: No my argument is incorrect. But solstafir's example looks better.